# How to delete bookmarks in NERDTree (Vim)?

Tags: vim, plugins, bookmarks

I checked the documentation but couldn't find it. Does anybody knows?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Put your cursor over the bookmark you want to delete and hit <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> (i.e. capital D).

If you hit <kbd>?</kbd> question mark while in the NERDTree window you'll find the docs for this. Search for "delete".

Comment: No matter what I tried I always got `NERDTree: Put your cursor on the booksmark`. I ended up moving it. lol

Comment: Turns out that NERDTree hides bookmarks that are invalid on restart. If that happens see the answer from @pratik-khadloya

Answer (score 55):

You can edit the `~/.NERDTreeBookmarks` file and delete it there.

Comment: Awesome, the exact answer I was looking for.  I changed the paths of some of my bookmarks so I couldn't re-adjust them the conventional way.

Comment: Nice tip.. How do you reload them without restarting Vim?  I delete the lines, then toggle bookmarks and nerdtree but the deleted bookmarks are still visible.

Answer (score 6):

The non-obvious thing is you have to put your cursor over the bookmark in the "Bookmarks" section, not within the tree itself. So if you don't have bookmarks already visible, hit B to see them, then put your cursor over one of those, and hit D to remove it. I just figured this out after a month of frustration :)

Answer (score 2):

1. First you go to **NERDTree** to find the bookmark by typing **`:NERDTree`**
2. Next, move your cursor to your bookmark's name, once this is selected type **`:D`**
3. You'll get a warning: Are you sure you wish to delete the bookmark: "MYBOOKMARK" (yN):
4. Make your choice, type **y** for yes or **N** for No.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NERDTree command: `:ClearBookmarks [<bookmark-name>]`

**or**

`Ctrl-w` move your cursor to NERDTree window, type `B` if your bookmark table is not displayed, select the bookmark you want to delete in the bookmark table, type `D` (i.e. `shift + d`)

**or**

`vim ~/.NERDTreeBookmarks` then delete the line which you want to delete

Read the documentation `:h NERDTree carefully`

Comment: You can also use `:ClearAllBookmarks` to remove all.